# MySql portable version

Tags: mysql, portability

anyone know a portable version of mysql?

I know xampp but it comes with PHP and Apache together

anyone know how to isolate the mysql?

Comment: do you mean a standalone version?

Comment: I don't think there is any such thing

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can download the MySQL Essentials version and make a few small changes to directories in the `my.ini` file to use relative paths instead of absolute paths. Then you can run the server directly without having to install or use a Windows service.

1. Download a MySQL `.zip` file (instead of an `.msi`, though you could get the `.msi` and use 7Zip or Orca to extract the files from it).
2. Extract the files. At a minimum you need the `bin` and `share` directories (actually, in `bin`, you really only need `mysqld.exe` as the absolute minimum to run a server).
3. Edit `my.ini` to change the `basedir` and `datadir` paths to something relative. For example:

   ```
   basedir=".."
   datadir="/MySQLdb"
   ```
4. If you do not have an existing database, then create one:

   ```
   mysqld --bootstrap
   ```
5. Run the server (you may need to use the `--skip-grant-tables` switch to get it running until you have set up your MySQL user):

   ```
   mysqld
   ```

   - To avoid the server being run in the current command-prompt, you can use the following to have it run in its own console which should disappear once it is running:

     ```
     start mysqld
     ```
   - If you get errors, delete the log files (e.g., `logs\ib_logfile*`) and run it again.

Comment: At least mysqld 5.1 seems to use the /data dir by default if you use the zipped version.

Comment: @Synetech, Why do you say that the files are extractable from the .msi? I've tried extracting with 7zip but the files are not there.

Comment: There is [an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24413426/how-to-bootstrap-mysql-on-windows) with `--bootstrap` on Windows that is resolved by just copying the data folder.

Comment: About 'bootstrap': running on windows says that is deprecated and invites to use --initialize

Answer (score 4):

Created a portable configuration at https://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-server-portable/

You should put your my.cnf or my.ini in a different directory than your data directory.

You will then need to initialize your portable version,

```
"\mysql-5.7.30-winx64\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="\mysql-5.7.30-winx64\config\my.ini" --standalone --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp --initialize
```

then you can start your portable version,

```
"\mysql-5.7.30-winx64\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="\mysql-5.7.30-winx64\config\my.ini" --standalone --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
```

Answer (score 3):

I think not, without counting on XAMPP. You don't have to use PHP or Apache anyway, just run the mysql from the .exe's