# Good options for a MySQL Lighter version

Tags: c#, mysql, windows, windows-installer, offline

I have a C#.NET application which connects to a MySQL database in a server.

I have a requirement to do some operations offline.( When the client machine does not have internet and cannot access the MySQL database.) My Plan is to create a MySQL database in local machine. Copy all files required to the local database and perform required operations. When the client machine have the access to the MySQL sever copy back the changed files to the server database.

My question is what are the good Options to use as local MySQL. Is there any lighter version of MySQL available?

I also need to install selected MySQL version with the windows installation package generated for my software.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: A little old, but see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13749988/111794) for how to use MySQL without an installation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It did not work for me..

Answer (score 0):

When I have these situations I usually fall back to SqlLight. Its a simple embeddable database, and if you are using only the simplest insert /select statements you should not need to maintain much difference between your local database access vs the remote database access.

That said. If you are using something that is not that simple it's usually a good advice to bite the bullet and do the whole mySql install thing on the local machine. Because the maintenance of 2 sets of database access will eat up development time like nothing else.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. Well my statements are not that simple... Therefore according to you I will have to install full MySQL in local machine. The other problem I have is If I include full MySQL installation to my msi (Windows Installer package for my software) It will became a very large file. Any ideas to handle that?

Comment: Before doing that try to run your mySql statements for sqlLight and check this link out which has the sql syntax for sqlLigth http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html specially check out the omission page. And remember no stored procedures are supported.

Comment: Thanks. I will check that. When I search on web I found Z-WAMP. Do you know anything about it. Thank You,

Comment: On the size of the installer, I don't really know. Its a question on its own. And I have never heard about Z-wamp sorry

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would use an embedded database with your offline application, something like FireBird where you don't need to install a 3rd party database etc. The FireBird dll's are linked and part of your application deployment. http://www.firebirdsql.org/

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Does is support MySQL databases?

Comment: No it has its own relational database. But I cant see a problem pushing data with SQL between FireBird and MySQL. You might even consider to just use FireBird which was previously called Interbase supported by Borland. So it is not a new kid on the block and has most features that are provided by other relational databases. And like i mentioned, you can use the embedded feature which makes your install footprint extremely small.