# How to bootstrap MySQL on Windows?

Tags: mysql, windows

I am trying to bootstrap mysqld on Windows 7 x64.  How should I do this?

(By 'bootstrap', I mean create the initial data directory and system tables.  I think I would use mysql_install_db for Unix, but the docs says this doesn't work for Windows?)

What I have done so far:

- I have a working MySQL installation.
- I am trying to make a new instance of mysqld using a different .ini file.
- I want to create the new instance of mysqld and its related files "from scratch" (i.e. I don't want to copy any files from the existing installation.

The exact command I am running is:

```
D:\MySQL5.6\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=my-test-server-C.ini --bootstrap --lc-messages-dir=D:\MySQL5.6\MySQL Server 5.6\share\ --character-sets-dir=D:\MySQL5.6\MySQL Server 5.6\share\charsets\
```

The file 'my-test-server-C.ini' does exist and appears to be valid.  I can provide any details from this if it would help.

After executing the command, there is no output on stderr.

I do see an error in 'test-server-C.err' about a "Bootstrap file error".  My understanding is that the --bootstrap option should create all the necessary tables?  I don't think this is a permissions problem.

The 'test-server-C.err' file contains the following:

```
2014-06-25 10:52:19 9540 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-06-25 10:52:19 9540 [Warning] option 'innodb-autoextend-increment': unsigned value 67108864 adjusted to 1000
2014-06-25 10:52:19 45c InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2014-06-25 10:52:19 9540 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-06-25 10:52:19 9540 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-06-25 10:52:19 9540 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-06-25 10:52:19 9540 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-06-25 10:52:19 9540 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 703.0M
2014-06-25 10:52:19 9540 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-06-25 10:52:19 9540 [Note] InnoDB: The first specified data file .\ibdata1 did not exist: a new database to be created!
2014-06-25 10:52:19 9540 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file .\ibdata1 size to 12 MB
2014-06-25 10:52:19 9540 [Note] InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
2014-06-25 10:52:19 9540 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile101 size to 48 MB
2014-06-25 10:52:19 9540 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile1 size to 48 MB
2014-06-25 10:52:20 9540 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file .\ib_logfile101 to .\ib_logfile0
2014-06-25 10:52:20 9540 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45781
2014-06-25 10:52:20 9540 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
2014-06-25 10:52:20 9540 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
2014-06-25 10:52:20 9540 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2014-06-25 10:52:20 9540 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2014-06-25 10:52:20 9540 [Note] InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
2014-06-25 10:52:20 9540 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.
2014-06-25 10:52:20 9540 [Note] InnoDB: Tablespace and datafile system tables created.
2014-06-25 10:52:20 9540 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2014-06-25 10:52:20 9540 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.12 started; log sequence number 0
2014-06-25 10:52:20 9540 [Note] RSA private key file not found: D:\Projects\mysqlab\data-test-server-C\\private_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2014-06-25 10:52:20 9540 [Note] RSA public key file not found: D:\Projects\mysqlab\data-test-server-C\\public_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
ERROR: 1105  Bootstrap file error, return code (32). Nearest query: ''
2014-06-25 10:52:20 9540 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-06-25 10:52:20 9540 [Note] Binlog end
2014-06-25 10:52:20 9540 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2014-06-25 10:52:20 9540 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2014-06-25 10:52:21 9540 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1600607
2014-06-25 10:52:21 9540 [Note] D:\MySQL5.6\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

### UPDATE 1

I have also tried not using a defaults file with the following command:

```
"D:\MySQL5.6\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe" --no-defaults --bootstrap --basedir=D:\Projects\mysqlab --datadir=D:\Projects\mysqlab\data-test-server-C --lc-messages-dir="D:\MySQL5.6\MySQL Server 5.6\share" --character-sets-dir="D:\MySQL5.6\MySQL Server 5.6\share\charsets"
```

This also results in ERROR: 1105  Bootstrap file error, return code (32). Nearest query: ''

### UPDATE 2

I have copied the private_key.pem and public_key.pem from the MySQL source msyql-server-5.6.17\mysql-test to my data directory.  This gets rid of the warnings about the missing RSA keys.  However, the same ERROR 115 still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that for Windows, the recommended way to do this is to simply copy the existing data directory from the .zip archive

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-data-directories.html

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Comment: I can confirm that this is also the case for MariaDB 10.2.7 on Windows 7 x64