# Install mysql without administration rights

Tags: mysql

When i click on mysql-installer-community-8.0.20.0.msi to install it, the window require me login with administration account as picture bellow. 
[image]

But my account is not administration privileges.
So is it possible Install mysql without administration rights ?

Comment: not possible to install without administrator permission. every user has some limitation

Comment: You can try running it without installing it.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42045494/running-starting-mysql-without-installation-on-windows