# Do we need to create a my.ini file for Mysql 8.0.33 when installing a noinstall ZIP Archive under Windows

Tags: mysql

In this question: [Running/Starting MySQL without installation on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42045494/running-starting-mysql-without-installation-on-windows), I have asked a question in the comment:

I see in many tutorials, there is a config file named `my.ini`. But in `Aj Tech Developer`'s answer, this `my.ini` file is not needed, why?

Here is a `my.ini` file I used for my configuration:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
port = 3306
max_connections=20
character-set-server=utf8
default-storage-engine=INNODB
```

**Question 1:**
It looks like if this file does not exist, the Mysql can still start correctly. So, is that file necessary?

**Question 2:**
Whey I try to create a database in the running Mysql, it said the server side default collation is `utf8mb3_general_ci`, while in some discussion([mysql - What's the difference between utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci)), it is suggested that the `utf8mb4_general_ci` is preferred. So, I'm not sure what are their difference.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

The server side collation option `utf8mb3_general_ci` is set by the `my.ini` file I put in the `<root>` folder of the MySQL. If I remove this `my.ini` file, and restart MySQL again. After that, I try to create a new database, I see the server side default collation is `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to create a `my.ini` or `my.cnf` file. Every server option has a compiled-in default. The default values are [documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html).

`utf8_general_ci` and `utf8_unicode_ci` are collations, not encodings.

I recommend using the MySQL 8.0 defaults: character set `utf8mb4` and collation `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` unless you have a specific need for something different (if you don't know whether you need something different, then you almost certainly don't).

If you want to know more details, then read the chapter on character sets and collations in the MySQL 8.0 manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset.html

I would also recommend reading the wikipedia article on UTF-8 for general information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Also this blog by Stack Overflow co-founder Joel Spolsky: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: Hi, Bill, thanks for the answer. I know UTF-8 and other other encoding. But I'm new in the MySQL world, I don't know the "collations". Let me remove my `my.ini`, and try to restart the MySQL again.

Comment: A collation is basically how the characters of a given encoding sort. In other words, given a pair of characters in an encoding, are they equal, or which one is less or greater than the other. There are multiple ways to sort characters, because different languages have different standards. Sometimes these standards change, so the general-purpose collation for UTF-8 has to be updated from time to time. The latest revision of the collation for UTF-8 supported by MySQL is named `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`.

Comment: Thanks, I have just remove `my.ini`, and I see the default collation is `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`, I have also updated my question about my finding.