# Minimum files to run MySQL or MariaDB server on Windows - (Portable MySQL/MariaDB)

Tags: mysql, database, deployment, mariadb

I am looking for minimum files required by MariaDB or MySQL to run without installing it like a portable server. I prefer MariaDB instead of MySQL. I want to embed it in my software written in Delphi. My software will able to start and stop the server as required. I have googled around but no success.

I have read an article https://rawgit.com/pts/portable-mariadb/master/portable_mariadb.html and http://www.bluecrownsoftware.com/article/271/Installing-MySQL-without-Root-Access-on-Linux but it is for Linux and I have no experience with it.

I have also read the article [MySql portable version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851174/mysql-portable-version) but this article mentioned MySQL Essential version and I am unable to find it.
It will be an extra value if I have some configuration file hints for successful running the server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Speaking of MariaDB, it is 2 files and 3 directories.

Layout is like this:

- bin\mysqld.exe
- share\errmsg.sys `# you can take it from share\english in normal installation or ZIP`
- data `# an empty directory`

you can start with

```
bin\mysqld.exe --console --skip-grant-tables
```

(last parameter is essential, as you do not have system tables).

It is missing system tables, if you need to create them, this will be a couple of more files.

this tool helps https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mysql_install_dbexe/ . `mysqld_install_db.exe` needs to be placed  next to `mysqld.exe` and then you can create system tables with

```
mysqld_install_db.exe --datadir=path-to-datadir
```

*UPDATE MariaDB 10.5.3 and later*

- bin\mysqld.exe
- bin\server.dll
- bin\mysql_install_db.exe (optional, run once to create data directory, can be removed afterwards)
- data

Changes compared to the previous versions : server.dll is new (mysqld.exe needs it), errmsg.sys is no more needed

Comment: you can connect as root user with empty password if your run --skip-grant-tables. if you create system tables with mysql_install_db.exe, the tool allows you to set roots password with --password option