# Mysql/MariaDB Private server with named pipes

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am doing something similar to this thread:
[Minimum files to run MySQL or MariaDB server on Windows - (Portable MySQL/MariaDB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42693809/minimum-files-to-run-mysql-or-mariadb-server-on-windows-portable-mysql-mariad)

Just want to add the following: add mysqld as a service and only use named pipes

Is that possible?

UPDATE:

I have a minimal mariadb install as per the folowing:

```
/bin/mysqld.exe
/bin/mysql_install_db.exe
/bin/server.dll
/bin/mysql.exe
```

I have run mysql_install_db.exe and it created the data directory(ies)
and the my.ini which I have edited to the follwing:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=c:/test/data
skip-networking=1
named-pipe=1
socket=//./pipe/isdlane1
```

ran `mysqld --install isdlane1`
which installed as a service, then started the service.. whihc started.
error log below:

```
2022-07-18 20:33:23 0 [Note] C:\test\bin\mysqld.exe: ready 
for connections.

Version: '10.8.3-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 0  mariadb.org 
binary distribution
```

So how do I connect to this with mysql.exe? I keep getting "access denied"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Access denied means a server is connecting, it just doesn't have the authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your [my.ini](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-with-option-files/#default-option-file-locations-on-windows) configuration include:

```
[client-server]
socket=isdlane1

[mariadb]

named-pipe
skip-networking

# optional
plugin_load_add = auth_named_pipe
```

You may also wish to consider [auth_named_pipe](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-named-pipe/) for streamless authentication.

Creating users is like:

```
CREATE USER neil IDENTIFIED VIA named_pipe;
grant all on *.* to neil with grant option
```

using whatever `%USERNAME%` you have.

I've you've lost root access, [this doc](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/troubleshooting-connection-issues/#unable-to-connect-to-a-running-server-lost-root-password) is a reference how to reset it or any authentication.

ref: [named_pipe](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#named_pipe), [skip-networking](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#skip_networking).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dan. so to specify a named pipe would I use --socket or --path?  does socket supersede path?

Comment: I can't see a `path` option, and it looks like [--socket](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/mariadb-10.9.1/sql/handle_connections_win.cc#L401) is used for the named pipe creation despite its very unix looking documentation.

Comment: Hi Dan, it's not path.. that was some jdbc stuff. using socket the service seems to start. but I can't connect. have updated original question... Thanks, N.